# Powershell loop through multiple files

Tags: sql-server, windows, powershell

I'm trying to loop through multiple files to see if a job completed. I'm very new to powershell and am trying to understand the basics of how looping works before creating a more detailed program. I can't figure out what's wrong in my code. When I run the program no output ("Success" or "Fail") is displayed. Any suggestions on looping through sql directory files to search for a specific string appreciated too:)

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\afila\Desktop\TEST" -Filter "*.txt" |
ForEach-Object{
if(Object.Contains("*Loaded successfully*"))
{
    Write-Host "Success" 
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Fail"
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Use $_ where you have Object.Contains.  It should read "$_.Contains".

Since you are using wildcards in your IF statement, you may also try -like.  -like, by default, treats the search with wildcards:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\afila\Desktop\TEST" -Filter "*.txt" |
ForEach-Object{
if($_ -like "Loaded successfully")
{
    Write-Host "Success" 
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Fail"
}
```

Comment: The entire purpose of `-like` is wildcard operations, so there is no other behavior.

Comment: That's what I said? "-Like treats the search with wildcards".

Answer (score 0):

When using the pipeline you have to use `$_` to represent the object passed down the pipeline. For example

```
Get-ChildItem C:\temp\ -Filter "txt" | 

Foreach-Object{
    if($_.Contains("my test info"))
    {
       write-host "success"
    }
}
```

The `$_` is similar to the word "this" in other languages and is just a representation of the current object.

Comment: It's nothing like `this` because that construct already exists within PowerShell.